# Google Analytics Account summaries

Tags: google-oauth, google-analytics-api

In order to get Google Analytics Account summaries information , I need
to make an HTTP call

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

But I am not sure from where I will get {YOUR_API_KEY} value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account summaries is private data.  That meaning that its data owned by the user who authenticates your application.

If you are accessing your own data then you can go to [Google Developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) and create service account credentials. Then follow the documentation for your programing language on how to authenticate using a service account.

If you are accessing data owned by another user then you will need to use Oauth2. you can go to [Google Developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) Oauth credentials.  Then follow the documentation for your programing language on how to authenticate using Oauth2.

The correct call for that would be a HTTP get to

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries?access_token={access token returned by one of the above}

The documentation for Authorization can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/authorization)

Comment: ok , so the url i mentioned was for service account .. right ?

Comment: The end point for the account summaries request(https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries)  is the same for a service account and for Oauth2.